# jquery ui menu appears transparent or behind other elements.

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

If you could be so kind to help me with CSS and a jQuery UI problem. I am new to these waters so I'll try to explain my need best I can.

I have used a jQuery UI accordion and a jQuery UI menu. Menu is inside of an active accordion "tab". When I open my menu, options appear, but the problem is that the accordion headers (of collapsed content) are over my menu options. Please check this jsFiddle, it will explain things better.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QAUbX/2/)

I have checked with FireBug, and this class `.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header` have `position: relative` and I think that is creating the problem, but when I turn off the property icons break. How can I make this work?

Thank you in advance, kind regards!

Comment: I think you forgot to post the link to jsfiddle.

Comment: Yes, you are right, first post and i couldn't even link to fiddle:). I want to thank the guy who was so kind to edit it. I have updated the jsFiddle and its working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy!! Just change your CSS to:

```
 .ui-menu { 
    width: 150px; 
    z-index: 2;
}
```

See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6LLnS/1/) here. **Remember** when you deal with positioned elements that are relative, absolute, or fixed then you may use [z-index](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/z-index) so alter the stacking order.